# jQuery .live() issue, not functioning?

Tags: jquery

I am using .live() in a site that im working on, and it seems it's not functioning well, here's my code:

```
$('.comment_cheer').live("click",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var id          = $(this).attr('rel');
    var url         = $(this).attr('href');
    var thisClass   = this;

    if(like2 == true){
    like2 = false;   

        setTimeout(function(){
            $.post(url,function(data){

                $(thisClass).fadeOut('slow').fadeIn();
                $(thisClass).removeClass('remove');
                $(thisClass).addClass('add');                            
                $('#boo_click_'+id).hide();

                like2 = true;
             });       
        },500);
    }

    return false;

});
```

what i wanted is after i post a comment i can choose to click between Cheer and Boo and when i click either one of them say for instance Cheer, the clickable Boo will disappear to prevent the user from clicking it, however it is not working what i wanted it to work. can someone please guide me over here?.

here's the code im using in my Cheer and Boo links:

```
    <!--Cheer!-->
<span id="cheer_click_<?php echo $all_post['comment_id'];?>" class="add" rel="<?php echo $all_post['comment_id']?>">
    <a  href    ="<?php echo base_url().'socket/likes/'.$all_post['comment_id']?>"
        class   ="comment_cheer"
        rel     ="<?php echo $all_post['comment_id']?>"
        target  ="num_likes_<?php echo $all_post['num_likes']?>"

    ><span><i class="cheer_icon button_icons_profile_13 padr5"></i>Cheer!</span></a>
</span>
<!--Boo!-->
<span id="boo_click_<?php echo $all_post['comment_id'];?>" class="remove red" rel="<?php echo $all_post['comment_id']?>">
    <a  href    ="<?php echo base_url().'socket/unlike/'.$all_post['comment_id']?>"
        class   ="comment_boo"
        rel     ="<?php echo $all_post['comment_id']?>"
        target  ="num_boos_<?php echo $all_post['num_likes']?>"

    ><span><i class="cheer_icon button_icons_profile_14 padr5"></i>Boo!</span></a>
</span>
```

Comment: You don't need `$.live` for this, since the click event bubbles and you don't seem to be adding the element `.comment_cheer` dynamically. Also, `$.live` is deprecated. Lastly, I don't see a an element with the class `comment_cheer`

Comment: Don't know what the problem is, but consider moving to `on()`, as `live()` is basicly deprecated, but it probably won't solve the issues you're having, and since i don't read fluid PHP-variable, it's hard to tell what's going on!

Comment: @JuanMendes, i have edited my post..take a look.,

Comment: my main problem is, i want that every time either Cheer or Boo is clicked, one of them will disappear so that user can not click it anymore. but what happens is that even i click Cheer, Boo link will still be there..

Comment: If you add a console.log(id) or alert(id) at the point where you have the .hide() statement does id have the expected value?

Comment: OK, then assuming you don't have more than one element with the same id I don't see why the `$('#boo_click_' + id).hide()` wouldn't work, sorry.

Comment: i click Cheer, Boo will disappear or both cheer and boo need to be disappear? and only one time clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the `like2` somewhere outside the click handler and give it the value `true`? If its not true or not defined, `Boo` will not disappear when you click `Cheer`. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratheepraj/tEbKw/). I've disabled the ajax post though.

The problem could also be that your ajax post fails and as a result the callback function does  not run. Do a console log inside the callback to make sure the function is called.